# Black bar overtop navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Im creating an app that uses a navigation controller for a couple of the views. When i finally figured out how to set it up this happened:

[image]

So obviously the black bar at the top is not supposed to be there, but i dont know what to do to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Comment: I think i figured out what you meant. It has been done.

Comment: I have the same problem since today (simultanously updated to Xcode 4.5, iOS 6.0 and OS X 10.8.2). In my sourcecode I nowhere do read or set any .frame-property. I create all views programmatically; there is no xib- or nib-file in my project. The black bar is visible on a real iPhone and on the simulator too (also when simulating 4"-display). When I replace the view by another view (by tapping on the tab-bar) the black bar goes away and stays away, even when I go back to the 1st view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also commonly seen when setting up a view programmatically. Be sure to use:

```
myView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

and not:

```
myView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: Thats weird, I always set up mine programatically and have never seen this problem before...

Comment: I have the same problem since today (simultanously updated to Xcode 4.5, iOS 6.0 and OS X 10.8.2). In my sourcecode I nowhere do read or set any .frame-property. I create all views programmatically; there is no xib- or nib-file in my project. The black bar is visible on a real iPhone and on the simulator too (also when simulating 4"-display). When I replace the view by another view (by tapping on the tab-bar) the black bar goes away and stays away, even when I go back to the 1st view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your view thinks it's supposed to have a status bar. Go into the XIB file and under the fourth tab in Simulated Metrics set Status Bar to None.